# Using Resolver to Register a View Model with "@Main Actor" Annotation

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, swiftui, async-await, resolver

My view model has multiple functions that use Task in order to execute use cases. I use the "@Main Actor" annotation for publishing UI updates on the main thread. I get an error when trying to register the view model in Resolver.

Is there a way to register these type of view models in Resolver?

**Error**

> Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous non isolated context

**Registering**

```
extension Resolver: ResolverRegistering {
    public static func registerAllServices() {
        register {
            MeetingListViewModel() as MeetingListViewModel
        }
        .scope(.graph)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
@MainActor
class MeetingListViewModel: ObservableObject {
   ...
}
```

**View**

```
struct MeetingListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: MeetingListViewModel = Resolver.resolve()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out we could simply add `@MainActor` to the Resolver extensions like so:

```
@MainActor
public static func registerWhatever() {
    ...
}
```

Same thing for the main function

```
@MainActor
public static func registerAllServices() {
    ...
}
```

It seems to work completely fine for me

Comment: Thanks, this works. Sorry for the late response!

Answer (score 1):

I have my solution it's problem born can't direct use instance property from viewModel but you can fix this like me by below Code (if you is same my case)

```
@MainActor class YourViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var  yourProperty: [String] = []

}
```

Then when you create file Unit test you can call like this after in.

```
var viewModel: YourViewModel!

@MainActor override func setUp() {
    serviceMock = MockDailyNewsService()
    vm = DailyNewsViewModel(service: serviceMock)
}

func testSearchNews_EmptySearchText() async throws {
     let listData = await vm.yourProperty
     XCTAssertTrue(listData.count > 0, "listData should not be empty")
}
```

Yeah I hope this post will be helpful for every one.